# Prevent <Input> textField from further text input during function-call

Tags: javascript, jquery

***Functionality:***

User pull external hand-lever and the jackpot reel will start to spin. The jackpot external hand-level is connected via USB and the trigger for the jackpot reel to spin is through a keypad character "*".

***Issue:***

At this point in time, whenever, the user pulls the lever, the  textfield will have an input of "*" to start spinning the jackpot reel. However, at any point of the spinning reel and when user pulls the lever again, the  textfield will have another input of "*", which the reel will continue to spin.

Hence, I would need to ask how am I able to stop the input of "*" character into the  textfield once there is already an initial "*" input or rather once the user pulls the hand reel lever for the first time and input the first "*" in the textfield, the  textfield will not be able to register any subsequent "*" no matter how many times the user pull during the jackpot spin reel.

***Code:***

```js
/***================= JACKPOT GAME METHOD: TRIGGER JACKPOT SPIN
     WHEN LEVER IS PULLED: special key to trigger is "*"" ==========================================
     ===============================================================
     ===========================================================***/

 $("#GamePlayCodeField").on("input", function(e) {

   // start game on Lever Pull
   game.restart();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="JackPotGamePage" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1920px; height:1080px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index=1; top:0px; left:1921px; margin:auto;">


  <!-- INVISIBLE INPUT FIELD FOR "*", GamePLay when user pulls the lever -->

  <input type="text" id="GamePlayCodeField" style="position:absolute; top:-500px; left:0px; height:160px; width:520px; outline: 1; border: 1; font-size:70px; font-color:white; font-family:'Arial'; background: transparent; z-index:100;" autofocus src="lib/image/transparent.png">

  <!-- JackPot Reel GamePlay -->
  <div id="reels">
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="380px" height="300px"></canvas>;
    <canvas id="canvas2" width="380px" height="300px"></canvas>;
    <canvas id="canvas3" width="380px" height="300px"></canvas>;
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you use a if statement

Answer (score 0):

You can `disable` the `input` while your function is running and re enable it after your function has finished.

```
$("GamePlayCodeField").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

To `enable input` after your function has completed

```
$("GamePlayCodeField").attr("disabled",false);
```

Or

```
$("GamePlayCodeField").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Although `.attr("disabled", false)` works in jQuery, it's purely legacy support for old code. (The correct attribute way would be `removeAttr("disabled")`.)  To use the `disabled` property with booleans, use `prop`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok i also add it in asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to prevent **the user** from adding anything to the field, the answer is set its `disabled` or `readonly` property:

```
$("selector-for-the-field").prop("disabled", true);
// or
$("selector-for-the-field").prop("readOnly", true);
```